# How can I limit the number of dropdown entries in a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have column A with a dropdown menu and a single option of "Yes". I want to limit the number of entries to 20, and ideally when that number is hit there is a pop up (similar to how data validation error works) telling the user why they can't select any more.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why not limit the no. of rows to 20?

Comment: Because the user may not always select the first 20 in the sheet, there are just over 200 rows and I want them to be able to select any of them.

Comment: Okay. I see. I think I have a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, data validation share the same feature with the function of dropdown list, so it seems no way to combine them together unless using Google Apps Script.

To limit A:A contains only 20 "Yes", you may use a custom formula

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "Yes")<=20
```

in the data validation setting sidebar.
[validation sidebar with a formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySMJ8.png)

Below is a spreadsheet as a demo with 5 as an upper bound:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fI7tndMfIRxuCtpuNJvAs54YQc_qiW5qI7-VUoUbTZo/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's not critical that the value is "Yes", but I do want it to be easy to select and not make the user type in the value. I wondered if maybe checkboxes would work, or some other method to "flag" the row, then use data validation to limit the number selected?

Comment: How about creating a column with all cells containing a check box, and using a formula to reflect changes from users? I created another sheet (demo 2) in the spreadsheet, and hope it helps!

Comment: I'm maybe asking for something that can't be done. For now I've decided to go with check boxes and then use conditional formatting to highlight the cells red when more than 20 have been selected. I'll wait for a little while to select your answer, just in case someone replies with a solution that meets all I've requested. Thank you for your prompt replies!

Comment: No problems and looking forward to learning something I do not know as well! I do not care if my answer is selected that much tho hahaha. Just want to help.

Comment: The method @vk26 provided below is brilliant and much better than mine! I learned something from answering this post and it is the best reward for me!!

Answer (score 1):

How about you try this method:

**1st**, Create a backend tab (Dropdown List Backend), and a column (Dropdown List) that will contain the values for your dropdown. Note that each of the cells in this column should only correspond to its equivalent dropdown cell in Dropdown Input Tab (Please see the sheet).

**2nd**, We add the formula below to the Dropdown List Column (See the image below):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF('Dropdown Input Here'!A2:A11="Yes","Yes",IF(COUNTIF('Dropdown Input Here'!$A$2:$A$11,"Yes")<5,"Yes",)))
```

[image]

This formula checks if its corresponding dropdown is "Yes." If true, then just return "Yes." Otherwise, we'll count the no. of "Yes" from the Dropdown Column. If the count is below the limit (in my example, I set the limit to 5), we return "Yes." Otherwise, we return Blank.

**Finally**, We link the the cells to their own dropdowns. To do that, we just highlight the column of the dropdowns and select the first cell in the Dropdown List Column from the Backend and make sure to make the row part of the reference Relative (No $).
Check if A2 Dropdown is linked to A2 from the backend, A3 Dropdown is linked to A3 Backend and so on.

[image]

Here's the sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wt38gES04IFbmEHNUBDqj32JHfEdnfqb0MLXQ3jntjo/edit#gid=2100307022

Note: Just expand the ranges in the formula to 200 (e.g., A2:A200).

Also, avoid copy-paste and dragging the cells with the dropdowns because it can break the links.